# Is ubuntu 18.10 using Wayland as default?

Tags: 18.10, wayland

Do you know please if ubuntu 18.10 uses wayland as default?

Comment: IMO it uses Xorg by default (they made a mistake by switching to Wayland as default since some xtool don't work in Wayland). But you can switch using gear icon on login screen and choosing "Ubuntu on Wayland". You can always check by running `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses X.Org. 18.10 release notes don't mention it, but [18.04 mentions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes) that they switched from Wayland to X.Org:

> X is the default display server. Wayland is provided as a Technical Preview and is expected to be the default display server in 20.04 LTS

Comment: Sorry we were writing answers at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

From: [Is this cuttlefish really all that cosmic? Ubuntu 18.10 arrives with extra spit, polish, 4.18 kernel](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/10/18/cosmic_cuttlefish/)

This:

> Wayland fans will be saddened but unsurprised to learn that Ubuntu
>   has, sensibly, stuck with X this time around, although you can switch
>   if you really want to. However, for most users, what comes out of the
>   box works more than adequately.